# How to add information on a try catch error chain, for a comprehensive stack trace?

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception

Taken this code:

```
try {
  try {
    try {
      throw new Error(`ERR00`)
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`ERR01`)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`ERR03`)
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error, (error as Error).stack);
}
```

The stack output will only report the most external error (topmost) but not the error chain.

Now imagine this error chain happen on distinct places func03 calls func02 calls func01
otherwise solution might be simple and wrap everything on a single trycatch.

Stack will only report error for func03 and will not be straightforward to backtrace the error. Without additional logging.

Like:

```
Error: ERR00
    at Object.<anonymous> (/[...]/test.ts:4:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:861:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:227:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:513:3) Error: ERR00
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nicola.aretini/Documents/github/nms-backend-services/nms.productful/test.ts:43:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:858:23)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:861:12)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at main (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:227:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:513:3)
```

How do you recommend to use Error class to fill up correctly the stack trace ?

To get something like:

```
Error: ERR03
    at Object.<anonymous> (/[...]/test.ts:4:15)
Error: ERR02
    at Object.<anonymous> (/[...]/test.ts:6:15)
Error: ERR01
    at Object.<anonymous> (/[...]/test.ts:8:15)

....
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`.cause` error property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/cause) (see the old [proposal page](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-error-cause) for more details) is meant to do:

```
try {
  try {
    try {
      throw new Error(`ERR00`)
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(`ERR01`, {cause: error})
    }
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`ERR03`, {cause: error})
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}
```

Comment: So meaning to say, there was the idea for this but it's archived and no other way around?

Comment: No, it's been archived ("set to read-only") after having been accepted, the feature is available in all recent JS implementations

Comment: How about Typescript? Also running your code as js, wont output what I expect. all the error messages thrown with a ref to the error code line.

Comment: [It's available in TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-6.html#--target-es2022) if you target `es2022` as well

Comment: Oh ok I see, but how about your console.error above? It is not actually dumping the cause/s or any ref... how are we  supposed to access to that info?

Comment: Hm, that seems to be an issue with the `console` implementation, I'd expect them to catch up… You can `console.dir(error)`, or traverse over `error.cause` manually.

Comment: See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1373321

Comment: Exactly this is reporting my same experience, cause is there but there is no way to access the cause at all ....

Comment: @koalaok "*there is no way to access the cause at all*" - sure there is, just refer to `error.cause`.